# Выборка из нескольких таблиц MySQL

Tags: запрос, mysql

Реально ли одним запросом узнать из таблицы тем `id` автора темы и `id` последнего сообщения, потом из таблицы пользователей ник автора темы, затем из таблицы сообщений узнать `id` автора последнего сообщения, и наконец опять из таблицы пользователей ник автора последнего сообщения?
Таблицы `topics` - темы, `posts` - сообщения, `users` - пользователи.
Пока получилось:

```
SELECT last_post, topics.author_id, topics.username AS author_username, posts.uid AS last_post_uid   
FROM topics   
LEFT JOIN users ON topics.author_id=users.id   
JOIN posts ON topics.last_post=posts.id
```

Проблема в том, что нужно из одной таблицы взять два разных значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
   t.last_post, 
   t.author_id, 
   p.author_id, 
   u1.username as theme_author, 
   u2.username as last_post_author 
from topics t
join posts p on t.last_post = p.id
join users u1 on t.author_id = u1.id
join users u2 on p.author_id = u2.id
where t.id = __id_нужной_темы__
```

Думаю, что как-то так..

Comment: Странно.. Своим умом сделал то же самое,только    
LEFT JOIN users AS pusers ON posts.uid=pusers.id   
Это моё AS убрать или оставить?

Comment: Можно и не убирать.