# комбинированная выборка из таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять, как сделать выборку из пары таблиц.

особенность в том, что таблицы связаны не один раз

в таблице 'записи' есть два поля, что завязаны на таблицу пользователей(поле users.id). "создатель" и "демонстратор"(тот кто разшарил запись).

в меру особенностей задачи, надо сделать выборку(желательно одним запросом), в которой будет логин и id как создателя, так и демонстратора записи(єто не считая общей инфы о самой записи(описание, дата создания, дата разшаривания и тд.). Но весь гуглеж на тему комбинированых выборок не дал результата.

может вы подскажете?

пока вижу только вариант с парой запросов, после чего объеденить результаты уже средствами PHP. Но жесткое ощущение того, что это костыль, не дает мне покоя.

Comment: Очень похоже на вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161455/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-mysql

Comment: я не совсем понял вопрос... имея структуру таблиц можно блоее детально сказать. Ну а что мешает поставить два условия в `JOIN`? Типа `SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.fld=t2.fld AND t1.fld2=t2.fld2`?

Comment: @cyadvert, посмотрите по ссылке из моего комментария, там в ответе берут два раза данные из таблицы пользователей через JOIN, вот это и имелось в виду.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо сделать объединение (*join*) с таблицей пользователей **два** раза, но по разным полям: один раз по полю с идентификатором «создателя», второй раз — «демонстратора».

а чтобы отличать поля из этих двух экземпляров одной и той же таблицы, при подключении следует использовать псевдонимы: `join таблица as псевдоним`.

пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84d74d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table u (id int, n text);
insert into u values (1, "шаляпин"), (2, "гостелерадио");

create table z (n text, s int, d int);
insert into z values ("из-за острова на стрежень", 1, 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select z.n as "название", u1.n as "создатель", u2.n as "демонстратор"
from z
left join u as u1
  on u1.id = z.s
left join u as u2
  on u2.id = z.d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84d74d/1/0)**:

```
|                         n |       n |            n |
|---------------------------|---------|--------------|
| из-за острова на стрежень | шаляпин | гостелерадио |
```