# Mysql Join Tables

Tags: mysql

Имеются две таблицы

1. Таблица 1 - описывает юзеров
2. Таблица 2- описывает сообщения отправленные юзерами

Вопрос, как Объеденить таблицы так , чтобы получить следующий набор
**id,nick_name_from,nick_name_to,message,date_time**

**[image: Таблица 1]**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: берем таблицу сообщений, джойним к ней таблицу пользователей как `Sender` по `from_id`, джойним еще раз ту же таблицу, но уже как `Receiver` и по `to_id`, выбираем нужные поля

Comment: @ВОРОН Создать два отдельных джоина получилось, а вот объединить их никак . Можете более подробно описать саму структуру джоинов, как она будет выглядит?

Comment: надо так: `...JOIN user AS Sender ON Sender.id = messages.from_id JOIN user AS Receiver ON Receiver.id = messages.to_id...`

Comment: @ВОРОН спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: В итоге вот что получилось .........................................................................................................................SELECT messages.id, receiver.nick_name as to_id ,messages.message, sender.nick_name as from_id, messages.date_time
      FROM messages
INNER JOIN user as sender
        ON sender.id = messages.from_id
INNER JOIN user as receiver
        ON receiver.id = messages.to_id

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, такой вопрос уже был и был не один, т.е. надо не отвечать, а закрывать как дубликат. Я быстро не смог найти, поэтому показал как делать, чтобы человек получил ответ и пошел дальше и закрытие вопроса его не смущало

Comment: @BOPOH, вот, навскидку, [мой ответ на аналогичный вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457556/178576).